# How to show a tooltip when specific rows of react DnD table are begin to be dragged in antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-dnd

I am using Ant Design's draggable table in a project. What I want is that when someone tries to drag first 2 rows of that table, a popup or tooltip or some kind of alert shows up telling that it can't be dragged. If not that, at least I want the DragPreview to show no animation of dragging being done so that it is clear that these rows are not meant to be dragged.

I tried many approaches but can't get anything done once the drag process is started. And I specifically want to show tooltip at the dragging time.

The following is the link to a code sandbox to produce minimum working example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-sammet-e41lf

A tooltip should be shown with a message when someone tries to drag first two rows of the table.

Comment: tooltip or a message? those are two different things

Comment: A tooltip preferably.

Answer (score 2):

I find this is the quickest way to show some message to a user that this `row` is not draggable.

**Method 1:**

When a user mouse `hover` an un-draggable row, it will simply turn red. You can customise this.

**index.css**

```
.ant-table-body
  tbody[class="ant-table-tbody"]
  tr[style="cursor: default;"]:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

**Method 2:**

When a user mouse `hover` an un-draggable row, it will show some message. You can customise this CSS as per your need.

[image: method-2]

**index.css**

```
.ant-table-body
  tbody[class="ant-table-tbody"]
  tr[style="cursor: default;"]:hover
  td:last-child:after {
  color: red;
  content: " THIS ROW IS NOT DRAGGABLE";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
```